# How can I get Cypress access other routes besides root within CI?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, gitlab-ci, cypress

I'm having issue allowing Cypress to test other routes besides "/" within CI builder.
I've come across [this](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-example-docker-compose/blob/master/e2e/cypress/integration/spec.js) repo where core developer demoed how to run spec tests when services are created and managed using `docker-compose`.

Unfortunately the repo isn't demoing how can I get Cypress to test other routes. I'm getting 200 on "/" but getting 404 on others.

`cypress.json`:

```
    {
  1   "baseUrl": "http://nginx:80",
  2   "video": false
  3 }
```

`docker-compose.yml`:

```
services:
    ...
    ...

    nginx:
       build:
          context: ./services/nginx
          dockerfile: Dockerfile
       restart: always
       ports:
         - 80:80
       depends_on:
         - users
         - client
```

Root route gives 200 but all other throw 404:

```
CypressError: `cy.visit()` failed trying to load:
http://nginx:80/register
The response we received from your web server was:
  > 404: Not Found
```

`nginx.conf` file:

```
server {
  listen 80;

  location / {
    proxy_pass        http://client:3000;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_redirect    default;
    proxy_set_header  Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header  Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_set_header  Host $host;
    proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
  }

  location /users {
    proxy_pass        http://users:5000;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_redirect    default;
    proxy_set_header  Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header  Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_set_header  Host $host;
    proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
  }

  location /auth {
    proxy_pass        http://users:5000;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_redirect    default;
    proxy_set_header  Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header  Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_set_header  Host $host;
    proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you have any "push state routing" configured for NGINX? If you're running an SPA it needs to return `index.html` for anything that's considered a client-side page.

Comment: I've added my Nginx config file. I never heard of "push state routing".